# Emacs redhat unwanted patchy reverse video font for HTML tags, directory listings, lines of code, etc

Tags: fonts, emacs, tags, redhat, reverse

The systems programmer installed a new version of redhat linux. Since then I've had to use an all-but unreadable version of emacs. Tags, labels, directories and so on in many different file types display as patchy "reverse video." The system programmer doesn't know how to fix this and won't install a different version of emacs. I can't find which variable setting (?) to reset to get rid of it. I don't know the name of the effect, or technical description of the parts of the files affected.

Running without my .emacs file does not help, and I've never seen this effect in thirty years of using emacs with a similar init file.

OS: RedHat 7.7 x86_64 Kernel: 3.10.0-1062.1.2.el7.x86_64

GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2018-09-12 on x86-039.build.eng.bos.redhat.com

[image: Example reverse video in directory listings]

[image: Showing reverse video tags for HTML]

Thanks in advance for any tips on what to add to my .emacs file to get rid of this effect!

Comment: Are you running Emacs inside a terminal (as opposed to as an X application with a GTK+ GUI)? Is it xterm, rxvt, or something else? What is the value of the `TERM` environment variable?

Comment: TERM is vt100. Not using Xwindows. Standard login via PuTTY. PuTTY settings same as always for years, and I could not find any PuTTY settings to address this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Try setting `TERM` to something else, perhaps `xterm`, `xterm-color`, `xterm-256color`. (Just enter `TERM=xterm` etc at the shell prompt, and start Emacs.)

Comment: IT WORKED! Whew. That was painless.Thank you so very much. My immediate large problem is solved. If you feel like sharing anything about where this got set differently -- which variable setting or configuration during the emacs install--I'll be prepared in the future. But in any case I am in your debt!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what might have changed here. When PuTTY connects to an SSH server, it sends a "terminal-type string".  As described in [section 4.15.3 of the PuTTY User Manual](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.73/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-termtype), this defaults to `xterm`, but can be changed if required.

Most modern systems should understand the `xterm` terminal type; I have vague memories of needing to change this to `vt100` when connecting to an old Solaris machine. When `TERM` is set to `vt100`, Emacs is going to look in [the terminfo database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) to understand what terminal features to use, and find that the [VT100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) doesn't support colours.  Thus, setting `TERM` to `xterm` solves the immediate problem.  Perhaps the terminal type has been overridden in a PuTTY configuration profile, or in a `.bashrc` file somewhere?

---

As for patchy reverse video, this is a result of Emacs "face" settings. A directory in Dired is displayed using [the `dired-directory` face](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/abb2515b0c5b2468f1c0d8345788063fda64ea80/lisp/dired.el#L464-L468):

```lisp
(defface dired-directory
  '((t (:inherit font-lock-function-name-face)))
  "Face used for subdirectories."
  :group 'dired-faces
  :version "22.1")
```

which in turn is based on [`font-lock-function-name-face`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/abb2515b0c5b2468f1c0d8345788063fda64ea80/lisp/font-lock.el#L2012-L2020):

```lisp
(defface font-lock-function-name-face
  '((((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) :foreground "Blue1")
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background dark))  :foreground "LightSkyBlue")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light)) :foreground "Blue")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark))  :foreground "LightSkyBlue")
    (((class color) (min-colors 8)) :foreground "blue" :weight bold)
    (t :inverse-video t :weight bold))
  "Font Lock mode face used to highlight function names."
  :group 'font-lock-faces)
```

As you can see, it uses different colours depending on how many colours the terminal supports (at least 8, at least 16, or at least 88) and whether the terminal background colour is light or dark.  The last setting applies when none of the others match, so when Emacs believes that the terminal does not support colours, it is going to use a bold inverse-video face.

Comment: Thank you so very much! Excellent.